# Stretching a sprite from point a to b starling

Tags: android, iphone, actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I am developing a mobile game for iOS and Android with Starling. I am very new to this framework. I need to add a sprite to the screen and then have the initial point on the screen that was touched be anchor point 1 and then the user will drag there finger which will adjust the second anchor point until they release their finger from the screen. Imagine several nodes that need connected by a line and you can picture what I am trying to do. The problem is that I can change the pivot to be at the beginning of the line but I dont know how to make the other anchor point work. I also cannot use anything other than a sprite as the line is animated by a sprite sheet. Any help that can be provided is greatly helpful, I have been thinking about this for a while now and can't seem to figure it out. Code is helpful and preferred but just giving me an outline of the concept would help as I can probably figure out code. Thanks!

Comment: have a look here: http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/touch_events

Answer (score 0):

I don't know actionscript but I'm sure if it is for android the touch event has 3 phases (generally): touch down, touch move, touch up.
You say you only have a sprite so define some variables:
initX, initY, finalX and finalY. All floats (or ints if you cast them). And a couple of booleans: set1 and set2 all false
On touch down you ask if set1== false if so, set initX=eventX and initY=eventY (eventX and eventY would be here the X and Y of the touch event). Then set set1=true
On touch move you do the same as above, with set2. if set2==false, set finalX=eventX and finalY=eventY, then set2=true.
and you draw your sprite from (initX,initY) to (finalX,finalY) or if you're using width/height then finalX-initX for the width, finalY-initY for height.
I hope this helped. I didn't even know starling existed but since it's actionscript it must be pretty close to java in its syntax

Comment: I agree with this however it all needs to happen in real time so as the user moves their finger I want the sprite's anchor 2 to follow while anchor 1 stays in place. If I understand correctly your solution will only work if the line is drawn after the user removes their finger? am i correct?

Comment: I don't believe so. I do not know the starling methods though, so there's no telling. Try it out and tell me f it worked

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment. What I wanted to say is that draw method works aside of touch event. In the android sdk you would call invalidate() at the end of the event, which is kind of a redraw. Since ActionScript uses kind of a dynamic pre-made GUI I guess it repaints itself at every frame. It wouldn't wait for the user to lift his finger either, since the event also works at every tick, setting the variables